# How to detect if an app is opened from custom url or notification - android

Tags: android, notifications, custom-url

I'm working on an app in android. It can be opened both from a custom URL and from a notification (when the user clicks on it). I've learned how to do both and know is working correctly.
What I want to know is how I can detect when it's open from the URL and when from the notification (it has to be some difference when I handle it in the Main activity).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple. Just set an extra boolean in the Intent and when activity is opened then check if it is opened from custom url or notification.

Let's say you are setting intent for Notification as following, put an extra in intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION",true);
```

In oncreate method of Activity check its value

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     boolean isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION",false);

}
```

Comment: Sorry Usman but I'm pretty new in android (I'm an iOS developer). Could you explain it a little better? Thanks!

Comment: But where do I have to put the first piece of code?

Comment: share your code where you are generating notification

Comment: I'm not generating it (at least in the app). I'm using Firebase cloud messaging. The notification is triggered in a server.